# Half-bridge converter input capacitor setup from boost PFC

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, power-factor-correction

I am using a uUC3854 for my boost PFC stage with an output power of 750 W. From my calculations of the output capacitor with a hold-up time of 25 ms and a maximum output voltage of 400 V and a minimum output voltage of 350 V I get a 1000 μF capacitor from the formula:

$$C_o=\frac{2\times P_{out}\times\Delta t}{{V_o}^2-{V_{o(min)}}^2}$$

My question is, do I have to connect two 2000 μF capacitors in series so as to use them at the input of the half-bridge converter or can I use one 1000 μF capacitor and afterwards place in parallel to it two smaller capacitors in series i.e. C<sub>b</sub> and C<sub>b</sub> from the image below)?

[image]

Comment: PFV = PFC (typo)?

Comment: I think having the two output capacitors stacked up is a possible idea but you may want to look at the transient behaviors as the capacitive junction point must be kept almost constant. See this [AN](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/and90103-d.pdf) on Fig. 51 where the author used dynamic balancing on the caps. Also, carefully look at the rms current with low- and high-frequency contributors.

Comment: @Verbal Kint what about using balancing resistors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to use two 2000 µF's in series, but this is probably a poor idea because of flux balancing in the transformer (or extenuating circumstances like fault current through a single failed transistor).  Likely better to use a single bulk cap (at V<sub>I</sub>), then film caps for the divider.

Also consider choosing a lower V<sub>min</sub> (lower primary *n*) or higher V<sub>max</sub>, to make better use of the bulk capacitance.  You show a forward converter topology, for which the input voltage range is reasonably flexible; more than a 2:1 range I would consider somewhat extreme, but up to 1.5:1 is still reasonably comfortable.

Comment: How do you calculate the film capacitors?

Comment: Set their sum such that the impedance gives a reasonably low ripple voltage at maximum load current. Say < 10%, or under 40Vpp. Take V/I = X, then minimum Fsw to get total C.

Comment: Do I need balancing resistors?

Comment: You can if you like. Also depends on initial conditions, if the inverter is ever disabled and what initial state it should be in for the next enable, how much leakage current flows through the bootstrap or other driver if any, etc. In short, anything secondary to what's shown in this question.

Comment: Thanks. If I use balancing resistors, do I need a dc blocking capacitor in series with the primary transformer winding?

Comment: What saturation current will your transformer primary have?

Comment: the saturation current will be around around 7A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141902/discussion-between-p-karis-and-tim-williams).